# Java Calling a MSSQL query containing a sequence Get Invalid Object

Tags: java, sql-server

I have written a query that has `NEXT VALUE FOR AVS_Interface_ControlID as controlID` which is a valid sequence.  I get the error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid object name 'AVS_Interface_ControlID'.
```

When I run this exact query in MSSQL Server Management Studio, I do not get an error and the sequence is displayed correctly and increments.  I've tried using dbo. and DBName.dbo. and those don't help.  I am logging into the DB as SA for both attempts.

Is "Next value for" not allowed with Java prepared statement calls?  or am I missing something?

Comment: That's an error coming from the database, telling you that it doesn't know what `AVS_Interface_ControlID` is in the current context.

Comment: I realize that it can't find that sequence, but I don't know why.  If I do DBName.dbo.AVS_Interface_ControlID it can't find it either when called from my code.  When I run in Management Studio, it does find it.  Also, the other data pulled in the query return fine if I remove this one item from the query.

Comment: Are you connected to the right database from java?

Comment: Yes, when I comment out the sequence, all of my other data comes out just fine.

Comment: Turns out I was in the wrong database.  Someone else on my team created the same database without an instance name and I was inadvertently connecting to that one, so my data was looking right because it was a clone of the same database, but without my newly created sequence.  Thanks for the help!